# c# winforms my ui still freeze with async in event load

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, asynchronous, async-await

In my event load of my form , I call a method `loadDg`:

```
private void form_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  loadDg();
}
```

and

```
private async Task loadDg()
        {
            pictureLoading.Visible = true;
            await Task.Run(() => { string[] datas = db.row("select * from products");
string[] datas2 = db.row("select * from users");
double one = Convert.ToInt32(datas[0]);
label1.Text = one.toString();
//....
});
pictureLoading.Visible = false; //hide gif animation 
}
```

in my code , db.row This method always returns only 1 row ( string array) , but my ui freezes still  , i try update UI continuously with async without freeze at startup

Comment: `label1.Text = ...` in non-ui thread is bad.

Comment: @Sinatr what's is the best way to fix it ?

Comment: @Flydog57 `loadDg` is not "called synchronously".  Given what's shown, it's an asynchronous method, and nothing is explicitly blocking until its completion in the code shown, so it will run asynchronously.  Marking `form_Load` as `async` would only be useful if you need to do something in response to the completion of the asynchronous method.  In this case, there is nothing being done when it finishes.

Comment: To fix the `label1.Text =...` issue, create a small function that sets the label and use `Control.Invoke` to invoke that function on the thread that owns the control (remember that the Form class is a sub-class of the control).  There are lots of examples on how to do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing to prevent your code run asynchronously. `pictureLoading` will be invisible even before task is completed. You should fix cross-thread problem and logic of the UI as this:

```
private void form_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  pictureLoading.Visible = true;
  loadDg();
}


private async Task loadDg()
{

    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        string[] datas = db.row("select * from products");
        string[] datas2 = db.row("select * from users");
        double one = Convert.ToInt32(datas[0]);

        label1.BeginInvoke((Action)delegate ()
        {
            label1.Text = one.toString();
            //hide gif animation 
            pictureLoading.Visible = false;
        });
        //....
    });

}
```

Comment: What's the benefit of invoking the UI thread from a thread pool thread and immediately get back to the UI thread?

Comment: @PauloMorgado Well for that simple case, your solution would be better. However, if the task is a loop and you want to update the UI multiple times, then the above code would be fine (but in that later case, sometime a `BackgroundWorker` might also works).

Comment: Or `IProgress`. But, in that case, you wouldn't be hiding `pictureLoading`. Would you?

Comment: @PauloMorgado 1.I tried to solve the problem with minimal changes in code. 2.The question had multiple UI updates in different lines. So, it may be easier this way. 3.Also, the method runs once in FormLoad which doesn't make me worried about resource usage.

Answer (score 0):

Unnecessarily jumping between threads/context should be avoided.

This is an with better resource usage:

```
private async void form_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    pictureLoading.Visible = true;

    try
    {
        label1.Text = await LoadDgAsync();
    }
    catch
    {
        // error handling
    }
    finally
    {
        pictureLoading.Visible = false;
    }
}


private Task<string> LoadDgAsync()
{
    return Task.Run(() =>
    {
        string[] datas = db.row("select * from products");
        string[] datas2 = db.row("select * from users");
        double one = Convert.ToInt32(datas[0]);

        //....

        return one.toString();
    });
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You are calling the `loadDg()` function synchronously.

Unless you await the `loadDg()` function call (since its return type is Task) and make the `form_Load` function asynchronous the function call will be synchronous.

The correct way to fix it is...

```
private async void form_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  await loadDg();
}
```

Comment: This is false.  Calling an asynchronous method doesn't run it synchronously.  The method would only run synchronously if it was a synchronous method from the start, and if that were true, then this code would behave no differently and would also run it synchronously.  `await` is a tool for more conveniently doing something after an asynchronous method completes.  As this code has nothing to do when the asynchronous method completes, it's accomplishing nothing.

Comment: @Servy maybe you can recommand another best approach to resolve this problem ?

Comment: @kevin73 You need to provide enough code to reproduce the problem for anyone to tell you how to fix it.